# Visual Studio stop auto rearranging If statements

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I had a bug in code and realised after some head-scratching it was caused by a really annoying feature in Visual Studio 2017 that I cannot figure out how to disable. Specifically when you start using If/Else/End If statements it tries to automatically close and fill in your code, auto indenting everything.

As you can see in my screenshot, doing this somehow resulted in a bug being created by the auto-complete via my updating of code.

Is there a way to stop it trying to be intelligent, i.e. make it work more like how braces work in C# code completion inside Visual Studio.

I don't normally write in VB.Net, just the odd bug-fix.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the bug is.  What was auto-completed?  What are the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be something done by Intellisense.

Comment: 8200 lines of code... *gulp*

Comment: Intellisense won't add the `Else`, or the code inside it `swDPUnTrace = openedSW` so this diff shows something made by humans in my humble opinion.

Comment: As @djv states, when the `If` and `Else` were typed in, the IDE will indent to a matched (the next) `End If`, which indented the existing `End If`. Once the new `End If` is also typed in, the original `End If` will outdent back to where it originally was. This is the designed behavior to the code formatting.  Just complete the code being added and all is fine.

Comment: You can still put this in one line `If openedSW Is Nothing Then swDPUnTrace = File.AppendText(filePathUnassigned) Else swDPUnTrace = openedSW` (approximation since I don't have the full code) without VS changing it. Or maybe I don't understand the question...

Comment: Or better yet, use null coalescing `swDPUnTrace = If(openedSW, File.AppendText(filePathUnassigned))`

Answer (score 0):

This `If` statement reformat from single-line to multi-line feature is since VS 2015. (Frankly I'm fine with it, and haven't had problems.) I don't think there is a setting (not under Tools->Options...->Text Editor->Basic, anyway) to disable it (maybe "Automatic insertion of end constructs" for this, but it would be draconian).

My suggestion is, if you find yourself in a situation where you need to squeeze in an `If` again, you can use Ctrl-Enter to open up a line above, then type it out. I'm guessing you started typing out `If openedSW is Nothing Then` right in front of, and on the same line as, the `swDPUnTrace = File.AppendText(...`, and so when when you pressed Enter-key, voila! The `Else` may have made an appearance via "Statement completion" auto list members.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to prevent Visual Studio from automatically changing the indentation of your existing code when you type an If statement, the following configuration option should do the trick. This works for me in Visual Studio 2019.

Go to the Tools menu, click Options..., navigate to Text Editor / Basic / Advanced, scroll down to the Editor Help box, and uncheck "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code." Now you can type whatever you want and Visual Studio will leave your existing indentation alone.

Of course, you can change the indentation of some code manually by selecting a few lines of code and pressing Tab to indent or Shift-Tab to unindent.

In my case, after I unchecked the "Pretty listing" option, I found that each new line I typed was starting at column 1 instead of starting at the same indentation level as the previous line. It turned out that the reason for that was that I had mistakenly changed the option Text Editor / Basic / Tabs / Indenting from "Smart" to "None"; changing it back to "Smart" made each line start at the indentation level I wanted.